# Adding a binary to the PATH from a Docker GitHub Action for use by later workflow steps

Tags: docker, github-actions

I am trying to create a Dockerfile based action that adds a program to the `$PATH` so that it can be used by later actions. My action runs code like this:

```sh
mkdir -p $GITHUB_WORKSPACE/bin
echo "echo Hello, world!" > $GITHUB_WORKSPACE/bin/hello-world
echo "::add-path::$GITHUB_WORKSPACE/bin"
```

My test workflow uses this like so:

```
jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1.0.0
      - name: Add program to path
        uses: ./
      - name: Use program
        run: hello-world
```

This fails because while the program has been added to `$GITHUB_WORKSPACE/bin/hello-world` the value of `$GITHUB_WORKSPACE` is different in the action and in the workspace step.

In the action it is `/github/workspace/`, while in the workflow it is `/home/runner/work/setup-gleam/setup-gleam/`, so the `$PATH` addition set by the action is not correct.

How can I add a file to a directory from a dockerfile based GitHub action so that it is on the path for the rest of the workflow? It seems that there is no writable `$PATH` directory shared between dockerfile actions and non-dockerfile actions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to update the PATH in a github action workflow file for a windows-latest hosted runner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60169752/how-to-update-the-path-in-a-github-action-workflow-file-for-a-windows-latest-hos)

Answer (score 1):

Runner path is stored in `$RUNNER_WORKSPACE` environment variable and can be used to get the right path.

```
echo "::add-path::$GITHUB_WORKSPACE/bin" # Make it accessible from docker containers
echo "::add-path::$RUNNER_WORKSPACE/$(basename $GITHUB_REPOSITORY)/bin" # Make it accessible from runner
```

But it looks more like a workaround than solution.

Comment: Error: The `add-path` command is disabled. Please upgrade to using Environment Files or opt into unsecure command execution by setting the `ACTIONS_ALLOW_UNSECURE_COMMANDS` environment variable to `true`. For more information see: https://github.blog/changelog/2020-10-01-github-actions-deprecating-set-env-and-add-path-commands/