# How to update the PATH in a github action workflow file for a windows-latest hosted runner

Tags: powershell, path, github-actions

I'm currently trying to add GitHub actions workflow to a repo...

To do a C++/CMake/swig/python development (i.e. native python library dev), I need to download and install swigwin and have it available in the `PATH`...

Unfortunately it seems the `$env:Path...` command is not take into account during the next  subsequent [steps](https://help.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idsteps)

## Example

```
name: Python Windows CI

on: [push, pull_request]

jobs:
  # Building using the GitHub runner environment directly.
  build:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Check cmake
      run: cmake --version
    - name: Install swig
      run: |
        (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile("http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/swig/swigwin-4.0.1.zip","swigwin-4.0.1.zip");
        Expand-Archive .\swigwin-4.0.1.zip .;
        $env:Path += ";.\swigwin-4.0.1";
        swig -version;
    - name: Check swig
      run: swig -version # swig cmdlet not found...
```

## Observed

```
> Set up job
> Run actions/checkout@v23s
> Check cmake
v Install swig
...
SWIG Version 4.0.1
...
v Check swig
 swig -version
  shell: C:\Program Files\PowerShell\6\pwsh.EXE -command ". '{0}'"
swig : The term 'swig' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At D:\a\_temp\0a8dc0e1-ec51-429b-abd0-cb3597e983ac.ps1:2 char:1
+ swig -version
+ ~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (swig:String) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

##[error]Process completed with exit code 1.
```

Comment: Does anyone know how to do it in ubuntu-latest instead of windows-latest?

Comment: For linux,  just run:  echo "/usr/path/whatever" >> $GITHUB_PATH  in a step, and the path will be updated for all subsequent steps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The other answers are a bit out of date (due to GitHub Actions deprecating add-path as explained in @Kel Solaar's answer), here's a full example based on @Mizux answer:

```yaml
    - name: Install swig
      if: "startsWith(runner.os, 'windows')"
      run: |
        (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile("http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/swig/swigwin-4.0.1.zip","swigwin-4.0.1.zip");
        Expand-Archive .\swigwin-4.0.1.zip .;
        echo "$((Get-Item .).FullName)/swigwin-4.0.1" | Out-File -FilePath $env:GITHUB_PATH -Encoding utf8 -Append
```

Another difference to @Mizus answer is that the absolute path to the swig directory is used, this is to ensure it still works even though the working directory changes.

Comment: Thanks! This worked to allow me to use Cppcheck in other steps after installing with choco 
`echo "$env:ProgramFiles\Cppcheck" | Out-File -FilePath $env:GITHUB_PATH -Encoding utf8 -Append`

Answer (score 33):

The `add-path` and `set-env` commands have been deprecated the 1st October 2020 for security reasons: https://github.blog/changelog/2020-10-01-github-actions-deprecating-set-env-and-add-path-commands/

The recommended way to add to %PATH% is using [environment files](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#environment-files) as follows:

Assuming you use `Powershell`, the default shell:

```
echo "C:\directory\to\add\to\path" | Out-File -FilePath $env:GITHUB_PATH -Encoding utf8 -Append
```

or alternatively for `bash`:

```
echo "C:\directory\to\add\to\path" >> $GITHUB_PATH
```

Comment: Does not work for me on the self hosted windows github runner.

Comment: This does not work for me. I'm running ubuntu-runner. And I used `echo "/path/to/commands" >> $GITHUB_PATH" and I still get `command not found`.

Comment: use echo `"/path/to/commands" >> $GITHUB_PATH` instead
Also use `$HOME` as part of your path/to/command instead of an absolute path, to avoid reference issues

Answer (score 14):

There is also a shorter way to achieve this in Powershell, which is the default shell that windows hosted runner uses:

`Add-Content $env:GITHUB_PATH "C:\directory\to\add\to\path"`

See [Add-Content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/add-content?view=powershell-7.2)

Comment: Thanks, so much time lost until I found this. I can't believe that this or the longer version isn't at https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#adding-a-system-path

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT: GitHub have deprecated this, please see other answer...**
ref: https://github.blog/changelog/2020-10-01-github-actions-deprecating-set-env-and-add-path-commands/

You must use the action syntax `echo "::add-path::..."`, in your case:

```
...
    - name: Install swig
      run: |
        (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile("http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/swig/swigwin-4.0.1.zip","swigwin-4.0.1.zip");
        Expand-Archive .\swigwin-4.0.1.zip .;
        echo "::add-path::./swigwin-4.0.1"
    - name: Check swig
      run: swig -version
```

src: https://help.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#adding-a-system-path

Comment: the link is not valid anymore

Comment: @jitter Link fixed ! seems Github doc writters follow my advice and reorganize the doc accordingly :D

Answer (score 1):

This is the way to do this now
`"/path/to/commands" >> $GITHUB_PATH`

Also use `$HOME` as part of your `path/to/command` instead of an absolute path, to avoid reference issues

https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#example-of-adding-a-system-path