# How to add a directory to PATH variable in GitHub Actions?

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a directory full of scripts and want to add them to the PATH variable to use my scripts as commands in my GitHub Actions.

I tried these lines but none of them worked:

```
echo 'PATH="${PATH}:/HolismHolding/Commands"' | sudo tee -a /etc/bash.bashrc
```

or

```
echo 'PATH="${PATH}:/HolismHolding/Commands"' >> $GITHUB_ENV
```

or

```
echo 'PATH="${PATH}:/HolismHolding/Commands"' >> $GITHUB_PATH
```

No matter what I do, I can't call my scripts as commands later in my actions. When I call the build script inside the /HolismHolding/Commands I get a command not found error.

I also tried this line, but I still get 'command not found':

```
echo "/HolismHolding/Commands" >> $GITHUB_PATH
```

Comment: When you use `GITHUB_PATH` you're not setting an env var, just supply the path itself: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64831469/3001761

Comment: please see the updated question. that solution did not work either.

Comment: Which machine are you using, linux or windows in github actions?

Comment: Also just to make sure if PATH variable is actually updating or not, you can perform `echo $PATH` if using linux

Answer (score 0):

One reason could be that you're using your commands in the same step or `run` command.

Test with another run command:

```
name: Temp

on:
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  testingPath:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:

      - name: Set Path
        run: |
          echo "/HolismHolding/Commands" >> $GITHUB_PATH
      
      - name: Get Path
        run: |
          echo $GITHUB_PATH
```

Quote from the [docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#adding-a-system-path)

> the currently running action cannot access the updated path variable.