# R system() and system2() not finding an executable on the path

Tags: r, github-actions

Here's my problem in a nutshell. This is on github actions on Windows:

```bash
     Rscript -e "system2('latexdiff', '--version')"
     Rscript -e "system('latexdiff --version')"
     latexdiff --version
```

Output:

```
Warning message:
In system2("latexdiff", "--version") : '"latexdiff"' not found
[1] 127
Warning message:
In system("latexdiff --version") : 'latexdiff' not found
This is LATEXDIFF 1.3.3 (Algorithm::Diff 1.15 fast, Perl v5.38.2)
  (c) 2004-2022 F J Tilmann
```

Why can I find latexdiff from the bash command line but not from within R?

Context: I updated the $PATH to include latexdiff in an earlier step.

Comment: How and where are you setting the path / same step / another step / exporting the variable? Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64831469/9960809) for setting the path in a windows runner help at all? Not sure what the difference would be between why R can't see it if it's set though, but I can't reproduce this.

Comment: I'm setting the path in a previous step, like this: `echo "$HOME/.local/bin/latexdiff" >> $GITHUB_PATH`, having previously moved the latexdiff folder into `$HOME/.local/bin`. This seems to work in that the `latexdiff --version` works directly from the bash command line.

Comment: I've also tried moving the file to `latexdiff.exe`. Then I get errors like :
`'latexdiff' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Comment: Setting the PATH like that is one way but is apparently not being seen/used by R. Verify `Sys.getenv("PATH")` in R to see what it thinks the path is. Are you avoiding using `system2(file.path(Sys.getenv("HOME"), ".local/bin/latexdiff.exe"), "--version")`?

Comment: You say "moved the latexdiff folder" ... so is there a _file_ `$HOME/.local/bin/latexdiff.exe` or is there a directory `$HOME/.local/bin/latexdiff/` that may contain your exe?

Comment: a directory, which in turn contains the file `latexdiff.pl`. I've checked the $PATH environment variable and indeed it contains the latexdiff directory.

Comment: Have you tried `shell('latexdiff --version')`?  As documented, `system()` and `system2()` don't use a shell, and you may need one to recognize that `latexdiff` means `latexdiff.pl`.

Comment: I have - see comments to the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

On windows, when a file is some form of executable (e.g., `.exe`, `.com`, `.bat`, and apparently `.pl`), a user can *omit* that extension when running it, so with a file named `quux.exe` you can call `quux` and it works. I don't know of any other OS that does that (automatically). R is definitely not doing that for you.

You said your file is named `latexdiff.pl`, so you should be call it as such. Try

```
     Rscript -e "system2('latexdiff.pl', '--version')"
     Rscript -e "system('latexdiff.pl --version')"
     latexdiff --version
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work. Nor does using `Rscript -e "shell('latexdiff.pl --version')"`. The error message is:
  
`'latexdiff.pl' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Warning message:
In shell("latexdiff.pl --version") :
  'latexdiff.pl --version' execution failed with error code 1`

Comment: A sidelight: running the shell command gives some informative messages. 
`shell: C:\rtools43\usr\bin\bash.EXE --noprofile --norc -e -o pipefail {0}
  env:
    GITHUB_PAT: ***
    R_KEEP_PKG_SOURCE: yes
    _R_INSTALL_TIME_PATCHES_: no
    R_LIBS_USER: D:\a\_temp\Library
    TZ: UTC
    _R_CHECK_SYSTEM_CLOCK_: FALSE
    NOT_CRAN: true
    RSPM: https://packagemanager.posit.co/cran/latest
    RENV_CONFIG_REPOS_OVERRIDE: https://packagemanager.posit.co/cran/latest`

Comment: Using `system2()` gives: `Warning message:
In system2("latexdiff.pl", "--version") : '"latexdiff.pl"' not found`. A similar message if I use `"latexdiff"` instead of `"latexdiff.pl"`.

Comment: My intuition here is that git bash is doing something special to update the `$PATH`, via the binary concealed within `$GITHUB_PATH`; and that while R gets this in its own environment, it does not pass it on when it runs its own shell, nor when it runs subcommands. (Its shell appears to be internal to R itself, judging by the output above?)

Comment: Something that is now working for me is `system2("perl", c("path/to/latexdiff.pl", "other arguments..."))`. This still leaves the question of how to let R learn the path to latexdiff.pl, but perhaps that can be figured out...

Comment: If you call `perl`, then `PATH` has nothing to do with it, nothing in R is going to infer it for you (i.e., R is not attempting to do something akin to the hash-bang `#!/usr/bin/perl` that many shells will do). You can look for it, perhaps with something like `Filter(file.exists, file.path(strsplit(Sys.getenv("PATH"), "[:;]")[[1]], "latexdiff.py"))` (which is then used in `system`).